# Collapse two dataframes and make an array strcuture

Tags: r, arrays, data-structures

```
data_1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("123","345","546","890"), V2 = c("J10","K12","R34","J17"),V3=c("N12","M34","W57","Q90"))
```

data_1
| V1 | V2 | V3 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 123  | J10    | N12 |
| 345  | K12    | M34 |
| 546  | N12    | R34 |
| 890  | J17    | J10 |

```
data_2 <-  data.frame(V1 = c("123","345","546","890"), V2 = c("01/02/90","10/04/21","09/03/95","29/03/90"),V3=c("28/07/86","16/02/87","17/10/56","14/01/60"))
```

data_2
| V1 | V2 | V3 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 123  | 01/02/90    | 28/07/86 |
| 345  | 10/04/21    | 16/02/87 |
| 546  | 09/03/95    | 17/10/56 |
| 890  | 29/03/90    | 14/01/60 |

I would like to have a common first column and collapse the data into a array structure

Result:
| V1 | J10 | N12 | K12 | M34 | R34 | J17 |
|:---- |:----:| :----:| :----: | :----: | :----: | ----:|
| 123  | 01/02/90 | 28/07/86 || |    |  |
| 345  | |  |10/04/21|16/02/87 |    |  |
| 546  | | 09/03/95 || |17/10/56    |  |
| 890  |14/01/60 |  || |    | 29/03/90 |

Answer (score 0):

We may reshape to 'long' format, bind the datasets and then reshape back to 'wide'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_cols(data_1 %>% 
       pivot_longer(cols = -V1), 
          data_2 %>% 
              pivot_longer(cols = -V1) %>% 
           select(-V1)) %>%
      select(-starts_with('name')) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = value...3, values_from = value...5)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 9
  V1    J10      N12      K12      M34      R34      W57      J17      Q90     
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 123   01/02/90 28/07/86 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    
2 345   <NA>     <NA>     10/04/21 16/02/87 <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>    
3 546   <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     09/03/95 17/10/56 <NA>     <NA>    
4 890   <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     <NA>     29/03/90 14/01/60
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data_1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("123","345","546","890"), V2 = c("J10","K12","R34","J17"),V3=c("N12","M34","W57","Q90"))
data_2 <- data.frame(V1 = c("123","345","546","890"), V2 = c("01/02/90","10/04/21","09/03/95","29/03/90"),V3=c("28/07/86","16/02/87","17/10/56","14/01/60"))

var_1 <- data.frame( V1= data_1$V1, VAR = data_1$V2, stringsAsFactors = F)
var_2 <- data.frame( V1= data_1$V1, VAR = data_1$V3, stringsAsFactors = F)
var <- bind_rows(var_1,var_2)

date_1 <- data.frame( V1= data_2$V1, DATE = data_2$V2, stringsAsFactors = F)
date_2 <- data.frame( V1= data_2$V1, DATE = data_2$V2, stringsAsFactors = F)
date <- bind_rows(date_1,date_2)

result <- left_join(var, date) %>% mutate_all(as.character) %>% distinct()

result <- result %>% pivot_wider(names_from = VAR, values_from = DATE)
result

V1    J10      K12      R34      J17      N12      M34      W57      Q90     
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 123   01/02/90 NA       NA       NA       01/02/90 NA       NA       NA      
2 345   NA       10/04/21 NA       NA       NA       10/04/21 NA       NA      
3 546   NA       NA       09/03/95 NA       NA       NA       09/03/95 NA      
4 890   NA       NA       NA       29/03/90 NA       NA       NA       29/03/90
```